# How to use translate in jquery Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have two languages on my website and I have this little script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#RFQForm").submit(function(){
  $("#RFQSubmit").prop('disabled', true).html('Uploading, please wait');
});  });
```

What is the propper way to translate this kind of strings in laravel? I tried to write two of these scripts with different strings and include it in `switch` statement but that seems like a dumb idea and it does not work.

Comment: Are you using this code on your blade or a .js file?

Comment: It's on blade view

Comment: Then so simple , change `html('Uploading, please wait');` to `html('{{ __('name.uploading, please wait') }}');` the the localization file will load from your `/lang/` directory, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization

Comment: I did not know you can use mustache inside javascript , you have brought great insight to me. I tought of that but would not even try it because I was so sure that it would not work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way in my opinion to use blade text into your js scripts/files is to pass data-* attributes on html elements.

e.g.
In your form you can pass translated text like this:

```
<form id="RFQForm" data-waiting-text="{{ __('name.uploading, please wait') }}">
```

And after in your jquery script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#RFQForm").submit(function(){
     $("#RFQSubmit").prop('disabled', true).html($(this).data('waiting-text'));
  });  
});
```